# vsftpd metasploit evidence in logs?

Tags: metasploit, ftp

We have a public ftp server that is being probed by the usual Chinese brute-force scans. They are probing vsftpd. Notmally a failed login to vsftpd looks like this in syslog:

```
Mar 17 15:56:07 cache0001 vsftpd: ftp_set_login_id - unable to esd_decode: root 
Mar 17 15:56:07 cache0001 vsftpd: ftp_authenticate failed - invalid login_id format: root ip: 10.90.3.193 
Mar 17 15:56:07 cache0001 vsftpd: Mon Mar 17 15:56:07 2014 [pid 13327] [root] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.90.3.193"
```

These logins look like this:

```
Mar 17 10:20:47 cache0001 vsftpd: Mon Mar 17 10:20:47 2014 [pid 10095] CONNECT: Client "61.147.76.54"
Mar 17 10:20:47 cache0001 vsftpd: ftp_authenticate failed - expired password: 2848358251 DTM20140317045711MjMxMzM1Nzk1 ip: 61.147.76.54 Current: DTM20140317102047 
Mar 17 10:20:47 cache0001 vsftpd: Mon Mar 17 10:20:47 2014 [pid 10095] [NTg3NTEwMTY1PDI4NDgzNTgyNTE+MjUxODUwNjU4] FAIL LOGIN: Client "61.147.76.54"
```

Not sure what's being logged here, there is no "invalid login_id" line, any why "expired password"?

Is this someone trying to use the Metasploit script for the vsftpd vulnerabilities that were out some time ago?

Thanks
-w